# Maya Batch Render in C++

Tags: c++, batch-processing, maya

I am trying to create a new command for maya to:
1. load the render settings profile
2. batch render the animation
3. save each image out based on a file format

I figured out how to do this in MEL or Python. I want to create the tool for C++. I have already looked into OpenMayaRender, but it seems that everything is for rendering to the viewport. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Or should I just use the scripting languages?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend sticking with script: it will be easier to develop and this does not sound like an application where the performance of the batch command itself will significantly affect throughput: you're talking fractions of a second to set up the job compared to minutes (or hours!) of rendering time.

Plus, if you go the C++ route you have to worry about supporting different OS/platform combinations.

The only exception would be if you have to support a format that Maya doesn't already support. Doing tons of per-pixel formatting would be very slow in mel or python. In that case you could create a file translator for your image file format and package it along with an MPXcommand to do the batch job.

Comment: Right, I understand all of that.

But I don't have to worry about OS, since we all use the same OS. And the tool is internal use only.

I don't need to affect the image before or after I render. I just don't know how to access the batch (software) render in Maya's OpenMayaRender